# What's the best way to check if an element exists in a firestore array, and if it does, run a function, and if not add it?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a 'like' button and currently the likes increment up by 1 each time the like button is clicked. However, I want to make this more robust and dynamic, and if a logged in user has already liked a post, then I want their 'like' to go away ala Facebook, Reddit (upvote), etc.

Currently what I'm doing is keeping track of the number of likes and who has liked a post. The structure looks like this:

```
post: {
  likes: 3,
  likedBy: ['userA', 'userB', 'userC']
}
```

So what I want to happen is: when the like button is clicked, I want to search the likedBy property to see if the logged in user has already liked the post, and then either increment liked by 1, and add them to the array, or decrement likes by 1 and remove them from the array.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write this logic with the React action that handles this interaction with firestore.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
export const newLike = (post) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore})  => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const signedInUser = getState().firebase.auth;
    console.log(signedInUser)
    firestore.collection('posts').doc(post.id).update({
      likes: (post.likes + 1),
      likedBy: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(signedInUser)
    }).then(()=> {
      dispatch({type: types.NEW_LIKE, post});
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: types.NEW_LIKE_ERROR, err});
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data structure, you don't need to keep `likes`, as you can get it from likedBy. I'm not familiar with firestore api, but logic below should do what you want, you just need to get/set date to/from firestore

```
  return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase, getFirestore})  => {
    const signedInUser = getState().firebase.auth;
    const posts = ...// get current state of post, with likedBy field. Also, I assume here, that likedBy is always an array, with data or empty
    let updatedLikedBy;
    if(posts.likedBy.indexOf(signedInUser) ===-1){ //assuming that signedInUser is a string
      updatedLikedBy = [...post.likedBy, signedInUser]
    } else {
      updatedLikedBy = post.likedBy.filter(item=>item!==signedInUser)
    }

    const updatedPost = {likedBy: updatedLikedBy} // now you can send this to firestore, and fire actions after success or fail.
  };
};
```

To get `likes` now you just need to do `posts.likedBy.length`